# creact-react-app - How to import Sass variables to files

Tags: reactjs, sass

I'm using create-react-app and I integrated Sass to it. It is compiling just fine, the issue is that if I create a variable or mixin, use it in one of my sass files and then close the localhost and comeback later and run `npm start`, it will give me an error, like this one:

[image]

The files are not recognizing the variables (mixin in this case), which is located in a file named "base.scss".

I also have an index.scss file where I import all my other .scss components:

```
@import "./styles/base.scss";
@import "./styles/layout.scss";
@import "./styles/components/search-bar.scss";
@import "./styles/components/side-nav.scss";
@import "./styles/components/phone-navigation.scss";
@import "./styles/components/card.scss";
@import "./styles/components/pagination.scss";
@import "./styles/components/dropdown.scss";
@import "./styles/components/dashboard.scss";
@import "./styles/components/cast.scss";
```

In the index.css file I can see the compiled code from all my .scss components, so it seems that it is working properly, I can see even the mixin in the compiled index.css file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find an answer? I think in create-react-app you need to `@import 'base'` for every components.scss file, otherwise the variables are not found.